# Lenovo T431s and and wireless don't play nicely

Tags: 12.04, wireless, intel-wireless

I just unboxed a lenovo T431s and installed ubuntu 12.04.2.  Everything went smoothly, but the wireless never came up.  I'm pulling a a dhcp properly with NM on my wired connection, but `ifconfig` doesn't even show wlan0 at all.

I poked around the web a bit and eventually downloaded the linux firmware from the intel website, but checking the `md5sum` with the file already in `/lib/firmware` they match.

I'm happy to post the output of other commands if they'll help, but lspci and lshw are below.

```
jth@t431s:~$ sudo lspci -nnkv | grep -A 10 Centrino
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 [8086:088f] (rev 24)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:5260]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
        Memory at f0c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
        Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [e0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 08-d4-0c-ff-ff-00-03-ed

jth@t431s:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 04
       serial: 3c:97:0e:92:d6:a1
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.0.0-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-3 ip=166.100.1.128 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:42 memory:f1500000-f151ffff memory:f153b000-f153bfff ioport:4080(size=32)
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Centrino Advanced-N 6235
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 24
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f0c00000-f0c01fff
```

---

As per the first comment, the output of said commands (modprobe has no output):

```
jth@t431s:~$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi
jth@t431s:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    2.713720] iwlwifi: Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux, in-tree:
[    2.713723] iwlwifi: Copyright(c) 2003-2012 Intel Corporation
jth@t431s:~$ rfkill list all
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
jth@t431s:~$
```

---

```
jth@t431s:~$ modinfo iwlwifi | grep 088F
alias:          pci:v00008086d0000088Fsv*sd00004260bc*sc*i*
jth@t431s:~$
```

---

full output of requested commands can be found [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5665705/)

The commands run were:

```
jth@t431s:~$ dmesg > justin.txt
jth@t431s:~$ lsmod >> justin.txt
jth@t431s:~$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep iwl >> justin.txt
```

Comment: What is the result of these commands? sudo modprobe iwlwifi; dmesg | grep iwl; rfkill list all

Comment: I wonder if the driver iwlwifi doesn't actually cover your device as early as 12.04. Please check: modinfo iwlwifi | grep 088F.

Comment: @chili555 edited.  For what its worth, I put 13.04 on initially and had similar results (but didn't explore my options very far).

Comment: The driver does cover your device. We need to find out why it doesn't stay loaded and create a wireless interface wlan0 on boot. Please detach any ethernet cable, reboot so we have a clean slate and run: dmesg > justin.txt; lsmod >> justin.txt; cat /var/log/syslog | grep iwl >> justin.txt. Find the file justin.txt in your user directory and paste it here so we can examine it: http://paste.ubuntu.com/ Please give us the link in your reply.

Comment: @chili555 updated question with pastebin link.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8768/discussion-between-justin-and-chili555)

Comment: I am in chat now.

Comment: I discovered that I could not install the patch on kernel Version 3.8.0-19 . I'm reproducing a useful comment @Justin added in response: > This is registered as a bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1180256) and is on its way into the mainstream
> kernel... I'm on 3.5.0-32 and it installs properly, but your issue may
> be worth adding to the bug report. You could try upgrading to 3.8.0-24
> (which is verified) working.

Comment: This is registered as a bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1180256) and is on its way into the mainstream kernel... I'm on 3.5.0-32 and it installs properly, but your issue may be worth adding to the bug report.  You could try upgrading to 3.8.0-24 (which is verified)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For posterity:

The issue was not with the kernel and instead with the `iwlwifi` driver.  A custom patch provided by one of the ubuntu kernel contributors fixed the problem and will be included in a patch eventually...

I stuck it up on my dropbox for the time being [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nbb8ml7dqut0gsv/wireless-iwlwifi-precise-dkms_3.6precise1sutton5_all.deb)

install with

```
dpkg -i wireless-iwlwifi-precise-dkms_3.6precise1sutton5_all.deb
```

Comment: As I also intend to buy such a device and therefore am very interested to know when it's officially fixed - is there an Ubuntu bugreport I can watch to see when the device will be running fine with standard Ubuntu software?

Comment: @Henning https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1180256

Comment: cool thanks! Apart from that, the system runs fine all around?